# When is sys.path modified?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sys

I'm having some difficulty understanding this paragraph in the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The
>   directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning
>   of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. **This means
>   that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of
>   the same name in the library directory.** This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more
>   information.

Say, I have the following module, named `demo.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print sys.path
```

There is another module named `sys.py` under the current directory, containing only a `pass`. I want to use this module to "shadow" the standard modules.

At the terminal, I executed and got

```
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:Documents sunqingyao$ python demo.py
['/Users/sunqingyao/Documents', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

So my question is: When is `sys.path` modified?

- If it's modified *before* `import sys` is executed, `sys.py` should be imported instead of the standard module.
- If it's modified *after* `print sys.path` is executed, `'/Users/sunqingyao/Documents'` shouldn't occur in `sys.path`.

And it's also weird that the modification happened between the execution of `import sys` and `print sys.path`.

Comment: You are confusing `sys.argv` and `sys.path` in your question. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: `sys` is a *built-in* module and cannot be masked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys` is a *built-in* module, it is part of the interpreter, and cannot be masked because it is already loaded when the interpreter starts.

That's because `sys.modules` is the core registry for modules being loaded, and `sys.modules['sys']` points to itself. Any `import sys` statement will find `sys.modules['sys']` before the module path needs to be searched.

`sys` is not the only built-in module, although it is the only one that is auto-loaded. See the the [`sys.builtin_module_names` tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) for the other modules that are compiled into your Python binary.

It is the responsibility of the [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) to update `sys.path`; it is loaded as part of the Python bootstrap process, unless you used the [`-S` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S).

Comment: One could note that without `sys` already being loaded, to give access to `sys.path`, the import mechanism wouldn't even know where to look for an external `sys` module.

Comment: But if `sys` is auto-loaded, why we need to write `import sys`?

Comment: @sunqingyao: `import` does **two** things: load the module if not yet loaded (inserting into `sys.modules`), and *bind the name in the current module*.

Comment: @sunqingyao: without `import sys` the name `sys` won't be available in your module. So `import sys` does not need to do the loading step, but is still needed to bind the name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And **after** I `import sys`, the command `print sys.bulitin_module_names` still raises an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bulitin_module_names'`. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @sunqingyao: look **closely** at what you typed. You didn't spell the name correctly.